# Rust signed modulo unsigned -> unsigned

Tags: rust, integer-overflow, modulo

In (stable) Rust, is there a relatively straightforward method of implementing the following function?

```rust
fn mod_euclid(val: i128, modulo: u128) -> u128;
```

Note the types! That is, 'standard' euclidean modulus (result is always in the range of `[0, mod)`), *avoiding spurious overflow/underflow in the intermediate calculation*. Some test cases:

```rust
// don't-care, just no panic or UB.
// Mild preference for treating this as though it was mod=1<<128 instead of 0.
assert_dc!(mod_euclid(i128::MAX,         0)); 
assert_dc!(mod_euclid(        0,         0)); 
assert_dc!(mod_euclid(i128::MIN,         0)); 

assert_eq!(mod_euclid(        1,        10),                  1);
assert_eq!(mod_euclid(       -1,        10),                  9);
assert_eq!(mod_euclid(       11,        10),                  1);
assert_eq!(mod_euclid(      -11,        10),                  9);
assert_eq!(mod_euclid(i128::MAX,         1),                  0);
assert_eq!(mod_euclid(        0,         1),                  0);
assert_eq!(mod_euclid(i128::MIN,         1),                  0);
assert_eq!(mod_euclid(i128::MAX, u128::MAX),  i128::MAX as u128);
assert_eq!(mod_euclid(        0, u128::MAX),                  0);
assert_eq!(mod_euclid(i128::MIN, u128::MAX),  i128::MAX as u128);
```

For signed%signed->signed, or unsigned%unsigned->unsigned, this is relatively straightforward. However, I can't find a good way of calculating signed % unsigned -> unsigned without converting one of the arguments - and as the last example illustrates, this may overflow or underflow no matter which direction you choose.

Comment: Note when writing tests you could just remove the `assert_dc!()` because if it panics then the test would fail by virtue of how tests work in Rust and UB is impossible in safe Rust (assuming there are no bugs).

Comment: @cafce25 - consider what happens if `mod_euclid` is marked `#[must_use]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no such function in the standard library, but it's not very difficult to write one yourself:

```rs
fn mod_euclid(a: i128, b: u128) -> u128 {
    if a >= 0 {
        (a as u128) % b
    } else {
        let r = (!a as u128) % b;
        b - r - 1
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e3572ecf3ef8445d2da123ee1a4f6a95)

How it works:

- If `a` is non-negative then it's straightforward - just use the unsigned remainder operator.
- Otherwise, the bitwise complement `!a` is non-negative (because the sign bit is flipped), and numerically equal to `-a - 1`. This means `r` is equivalent to `b - a - 1` modulo `b`, and hence `b - r - 1` is equivalent to `a` modulo `b`. Conveniently, `b - r - 1` is in the expected range `0..b`.

Comment: Panics if `b == 0`, opposed to what the unit test requires.

Comment: @Finomnis It is trivial to add a condition for `if b == 0` to give it whatever behaviour you want for that case. There is no mathematically sensible option, so I did not choose one. For most use-cases it is preferable to get an error than a nonsense result.

Comment: @kaya3 The mathematically sensible option is to [return the other operand](https://mathoverflow.net/a/359519/157594).

Comment: @user3840170 Well that sucks in our case, because they aren't the same types :D

Comment: @user3840170 You can make an argument that the remainder modulo 0 should be defined that way, but mathematically it is not defined that way. Doing so violates the basic property that `a mod b` is in the half-open range `0..b`. Either way, if you want your modulo to give some unusual result that happens to be useful to you in the case `b = 0`, you can define that behaviour for yourself.

Comment: In this case it's mildly preferential to treat a modulo of 0 as if it "actually" meant 1<<128, but I don't care too much.

Comment: In that case you can write `if b == 0 { a as u128 } else ...`, since a straight cast gives the same value modulo 2^128. I doubt there is anyone else who will want that behaviour rather than an error, so I will leave the answer as it is.

Comment: Is there a decent explanation anywhere of what precisely the Rust integer casting rules are? I was under the (obviously-erroneous) assumption that e.g. `-1 as u128` would panic.

Comment: @TLW See the [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#numeric-cast): *Casting between two integers of the same size (e.g. i32 -> u32) is a no-op (Rust uses 2's complement for negative values of fixed integers)*.

Comment: @kaya3 Not that real mathematicians ever speak of ‘the modulo operator’ or even of a ‘true definition’ of a mathematical concept, but Knuth defines _a_ mod 0 := _a_. (TAoCP vol. I 1969, §1.2.4, p. 38).

Comment: @user3840170 Your quotes around the phrases "the modulo operator" and "true definition" are not quoting me, as I did not use those terms. The point is not that there is a proper definition that disagrees with the definition you propose, rather that there is no generally accepted definition. You will also find some sources define `0^0 = 1` but that is likewise not generally accepted. Any definition you choose to accept is up to you, but it will violate at least one property that is otherwise normally assumed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little bit more straight forward, use `rem_euclid` where possible and else return the positive value equivalent to `a`:

```rust
pub fn mod_euclid(a: i128, b: u128) -> u128 {
    const UPPER: u128 = i128::MAX as u128;
    match b {
        1..=UPPER => a.rem_euclid(b as i128) as u128,
        _ if a >= 0 => a as u128,
        // turn a from two's complement negative into it's
        // equivalent positive value by adding u128::MAX
        // essentialy calculating u128::MAX - |a|
        _ => u128::MAX.wrapping_add_signed(a),
        //_ => a as u128 - (a < 0) as u128,
    }
}
```

(The parser didn't like my casting in the match hence `UPPER`)

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=855253ae4e14fb921b606328f041eeb4)

Results in a [little fewer instructions & jumps on x86_64](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/KoPfbjn8e) as well.

Comment: "more straightforward", you say, about `a as u128 - (a < 0) as u128` for the large-b case.  I hesitate to ask what you consider non-straightforward...

Comment: I see what it does - I don't understand why it works.

Comment: Fair :D, I replaced it with the explicit version which compiles to the same assembly (at least on x86) @TLW

Comment: Much clearer, thank you!